# Twitter auth using Firebase for iOS 13 not working

Tags: swift5

I am getting below error while I try to run the build. I followed Firebase document as it is. Any solution for this issue?[please open link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsmp4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
Auth().signIn(with: credential!)
```

with:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!)
```